# Find, copy and paste in different worksheets using the Find function

Tags: excel, vba

With the following macro I was trying to search in a `worksheet ("Sheet11")` for a certain header, copy the rows below it using a `loop (x = 0 to 10)`, search for the same header in a different `worksheet ("Sheet22")` and paste the copied stuff under exactly the same header.

[image]

[image]

```
Sub FindCopyPasteV8()

Dim FindH1 As Range

Dim TestR1 As Range
Dim TestR2 As Range

Dim StartRow1 As Long
Dim StartColumn1 As Long
Dim StartRow2 As Long
Dim StartColumn2 As Long

Dim x As Long

   With Sheets("Sheet11").Range("A:FF")

      Set FindH1 = .Find(What:="Header 1", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

   End With

   With Sheets("Sheet22").Range("A:FF")

      Set TestR1 = .Find(What:="Header 1", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

      For x = 0 To 10

         StartColumn1 = TestR1.Column
         StartColumn2 = FindH1.Column

         StartRow1 = TestR1.Row + x
         StartRow2 = FindH1.Row + x

         Set TestR1 = Sheets("Sheet22").Cells(StartRow1, StartColumn1)
         Set TestR2 = Sheets("Sheet11").Cells(StartRow2, StartColumn2)

         TestR2.Copy TestR1

     Next x

  End With

End Sub
```

It doesn't work and I don't know why. I get an error in the line `StartColumn1 = TestR1.Column` The error message is "runtime error 91 object variable or with block variable not set".

I know that the same result could be achieved with easier programming but for my intended use it must work **exactly** like shown above with a loop and the Find function.

Comment: why does it have to have a loop?

Comment: @John Demian in order to be in the safe site you should use 2 checks, if `FindH1` & `TestR1` is not nothing. Also is more efficient if you narrow down the search area, from `A:FF` to `A1:FF1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That simply tells that the range TestR1 has not been set so you cannot access it's properties.

While using Find method, always check to make sure that the range you are searching for is found before proceeding further.

And you can do so like this...

```
With Sheets("Sheet22").Range("A:FF")
    Set TestR1 = .Find(What:="Header 1", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not TestR1 Is Nothing Then
        For x = 0 To 10
            StartColumn1 = TestR1.Column
            StartColumn2 = FindH1.Column

            StartRow1 = TestR1.Row + x
            StartRow2 = FindH1.Row + x

            Set TestR1 = Sheets("Sheet22").Cells(StartRow1, StartColumn1)
            Set TestR2 = Sheets("Sheet11").Cells(StartRow2, StartColumn2)

            TestR2.Copy TestR1
        Next x
    Else
        MsgBox "Header 1 was not found on Sheet22.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use copy-paste

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindCopyPasteV8()

    Dim FindH1 As Range, TestR1 As Range
    Dim LastRow11 As Long, lastRow22 As Long

    Dim ws11 As Worksheet, ws22 As Worksheet

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws11 = .Worksheets("Sheet11")
        Set ws22 = .Worksheets("Sheet22")
    End With

    'Eliminate searching range to search in the first row only
    Set FindH1 = ws11.Range("A1:FF1").Find(What:="Header 1", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

    'If Header 1 found in Sheet11
    If Not FindH1 Is Nothing Then

        Set TestR1 = ws22.Range("A1:FF1").Find(What:="Header 1", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

        'If Header 1 found in Sheet22
        If Not TestR1 Is Nothing Then
            'Find last row of the column where Header 1 found in Sheet11
            LastRow11 = ws11.Cells(ws11.Rows.Count, FindH1.Column).End(xlUp).Row
            'Find last row of the column where Header 1 found in Sheet22
            lastRow22 = ws22.Cells(ws11.Rows.Count, FindH1.Column).End(xlUp).Row
            'Copy range from sheet11
            ws11.Range(ws11.Cells(2, FindH1.Column), ws11.Cells(LastRow11, FindH1.Column)).Copy
            'Paste range to sheet22
            ws22.Cells(lastRow22 + 1, TestR1.Column).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Else
            'If Header not found in Sheet22
            MsgBox "Header 1 was not found on Sheet22.", vbExclamation
        End If

    Else
        'If Header 1 not found in Sheet11
        MsgBox "Header 1 was not found on Sheet11.", vbExclamation
    End If

End Sub
```